# no instance of play.api.libs.json.format is available for scala.option[scala.any]

Tags: scala, case-class, play-json

I just trying to create Json format (using play json) of a case class which contains a field of Any data type in Scala

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json}
case class Basics(
                   label:Option[String],
                   key:Option[String],
                   name:Option[String],
                   value:Option[Any],
                   field_type:Option[String]
                 )
object Basics{
  implicit val format:Format[Basics]=Json.format
}
```

When I compiling my code it says that..

```
no instance of play.api.libs.json.format is available for scala.option[scala.any]
```

I am taking Any type because the 'value' field might be a String or a Boolean Type.
Any suggestion that I am missing something?

Comment: There is no way type class mechanism would work properly with `Any`. That totally defeat it. Anyway, `Any` is far from recommended, specially as case class property.

Answer (score -2):

Found a solution for it..

```
   object Basics{
  implicit val anyReads: Reads[Any] = Reads[Any](m => JsonFormatConverter.metaValueToJsValue(m))
  implicit val WritesAny: Writes[Any] = JsonFormatConverter.anyWrite
  implicit val format:Format[Basics] = Json.format[Basics]
}

object JsonFormatConverter {

  def metaValueToJsValue(m: JsValue): JsResult[Any] = {
    m match {
      case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(s)
      case JsBoolean(b) => JsSuccess(b)
    }
  }

  val anyWrite:Writes[Any]=Writes[Any]{
  res=>
   res match {
      case x: String => JsString(x)
      case x: Boolean => JsBoolean(x)
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Declaring a `Reads` (or any type class instance) for `Any` is a bad idea and will surely lead to implicit resolution issue